# Adding Data to Array With FetchAPI

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fetch-api

I need to send an object to a backend function that is then supposed to send a response and add a new table row in the frontend. The table row will be added just fine as long as I can get the data to the backend function. How can I send the row object to the backend function and then push the result to the array?

This is being performed in a Vue component.

JS

```
data: function () { return }
table: [] }
}

    newRow: function () {
        var row = { Id: 0, Color: '', Model: 0, Type: 0 };
        fetch("/Contr/Function", {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify(row)
        }
        ).then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        })
            .then(function (table) {
                table.push(row);
            });
    },
```

Comment: You don't seem to be assigning the response value to this `table` object in the `data`.

Comment: @kas I was told that the backend function would send a new object upon receiving the empty object initially. So would using "row" work instead? It still gives me a backend exception.

Comment: what's the exception?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
Index:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: That's from the JavaScript log... the backend exception is...

Comment: System.Reflection.TargetException: 'Non-static method requires a target.'

Comment: One more thing can you please modify snippet i question so that structure of root object is clear?

Comment: newObject doesn't seem to be defined, and modifying the table object that's returned from the Fetch API doesn't seem like it would have any lasting effect. I think you should read up on [Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to understand how the promises work.

Comment: Can you please not send `Id` as attribute in row and try?

Comment: I see you updated your question so the variable names aren't the same anymore. You're still essentially updating the data that is returned by the Fetch API, so there won't be any lasting effect.

Comment: @kas I have read that before but it's a huge wall over overtly verbose text; didn't get anything from it that helped me here. :(

Comment: @JackOfAshes-MohitGawande Sadly it still returns the same exception.

Comment: @kas table.push(row) change this to data as well, or just the parameter in the function?

Comment: You likely want to rename the "table" variable inside the last promise to "data", since in the promise you want to perform an operation with the data that's returned by the promise. Then you can perform the operation you want on the table variable using the data that is returned by the promise.

Comment: @kas So even just trying to get a console log from the second "then" promise gets an error. So I guess the object is not compatible with the formatting or something? It seems to be happening before it reaches that area of the code now, as I commented out the push line after making your suggested changes.